# Can asynchronous module definitions be used with abstract syntax trees on v8 engine to read third party dependencies? This is for Cloudflare Workers

Tags: node.js, v8, abstract-syntax-tree, amd, cloudflare-workers

I understand `eval` string-to-function is impossible to use on the browsers' application programming interfaces, but there must be another strategy to use third party dependencies without `node.js` on `v8 engine`, given *Cloudflare does it in-house, unless they disable the exclusive method by necessity or otherwise on their edge servers for Workers. I imagine I could gather the `AST` of the `commonjs` `module`, as I was able to by `rollup` `watch`*, but **what might the actual steps be, by tooling**? I mention `AMD` for it seems to rely on string-to-function (*to-which I've notice Mozilla MDN says nothing much about it*).

[I have](https://github.com/NickCarducci/mastercard-backbank) been [exploring](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-darwin-8jcl2k?file=/src/mastercard-backbank) the require.js repositories, and they either use `eval` or `AST`

```
function DEFNODE(type, props, methods, base) {
    if (arguments.length < 4) base = AST_Node;
    if (!props) props = [];
    else props = props.split(/\s+/);
    var self_props = props;
    if (base && base.PROPS) props = props.concat(base.PROPS);
    var code = "return function AST_" + type + "(props){ if (props) { ";
    for (var i = props.length; --i >= 0; ) {
      code += "this." + props[i] + " = props." + props[i] + ";";
    }
    var proto = base && new base();
    if ((proto && proto.initialize) || (methods && methods.initialize))
      code += "this.initialize();";
    code += "}}";
    //constructor
    var cnstor = new Function(code)();
    if (proto) {
      cnstor.prototype = proto;
      cnstor.BASE = base;
    }
    if (base) base.SUBCLASSES.push(cnstor);
    cnstor.prototype.CTOR = cnstor;
    cnstor.PROPS = props || null;
    cnstor.SELF_PROPS = self_props;
    cnstor.SUBCLASSES = [];
    if (type) {
      cnstor.prototype.TYPE = cnstor.TYPE = type;
    }
    if (methods)
      for (i in methods)
        if (HOP(methods, i)) {
          if (/^\$/.test(i)) {
            cnstor[i.substr(1)] = methods[i];
          } else {
            cnstor.prototype[i] = methods[i];
          }
        }
    //a function that returns an object with [name]:method
    cnstor.DEFMETHOD = function (name, method) {
      this.prototype[name] = method;
    };
    if (typeof exports !== "undefined") exports[`AST_${type}`] = cnstor;

    return cnstor;
  }

  var AST_Token = DEFNODE(
    "Token",
    "type value line col pos endline endcol endpos nlb comments_before file raw",
    {},
    null
  );
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-darwin-8jcl2k?file=/src/mastercard-backbank/uglify/index.js

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EF7UW9HxOe4
[image: HTML5/JavaScript with Maven]

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking how to load third-party libraries in a CloudFlare worker? A quick web search finds https://community.cloudflare.com/t/how-to-import-third-party-library-files-in-the-worker/16009, does that help?

Comment: I also don't understand the question. I've read it a few times and I really have no idea what you're asking about, @NickCarducci

Comment: Can anonymous module definitions use AST to bypass the use of third party transpilers? How are commonjs modules exported, after compiling? Is there an AST that is consumable, or is that only with rollup watch that I was able to view with v8 controlled by a Cloudflare Worker. Does Webpack (1) use `eval`, or (2) do they manage to transpile with AST, under the hood, and I should try to use require.js and r.js source code. I forget why I started looking (edited in question) vs. webpack, yet I am here asking for I’ve found this page "uglify" in https://github.com/requirejs/r.js/tree/master/dist

Comment: I'm still lost. FWIW, all "transipiling" performed by Cloudflare Workers happens in the command-line tooling *before* anything is uploaded to Cloudflare. It's accomplished by shelling out to standard tools like rollup, nothing Cloudflare-specific. Whereas Cloudflare's use of a custom V8 runtime is when actually executing the code. So I don't understand what you're getting at about transpiling having something to do with the custom V8 runtime.

Comment: I think I am lost because of this blog post https://blog.cloudflare.com/node-js-support-cloudflare-workers/ I certainly encountered issues in this version of my Durable Object Worker https://github.com/NickCarducci/mastercard-backbank/tree/a12bb23007f1917a3786197b6fd779c044320df7/src `import * as locs from "mastercard-locations";
import * as places from "mastercard-places";` basing off of the example https://github.com/cloudflare/durable-objects-rollup-esm/issues/13 I guess I'd rather use package.json for dependencies like these of interest to me instead of hit that built limit, probably.

Comment: NodeResolve still uses require

Comment: This shouldn't be a different question if the answer can be to write a java program.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to make a C++ addon just to add a default object  for
> node.js named exports or am I Y’ing up the wrong X

```
'.so' shared library for C++ dlopen/LoadLibrary (or #include?)
```

“I have to say that I'm amazed that there is code out there that loads one native addon from another native addon! Is it done by acquiring and then calling an instance of the require() function, or perhaps by [using uv_dlopen() directly](https://www.quora.com/Are-trade-secrets-property-or-exclusionary-monopolies/answer/Nick-Carducci)?”

[N-API: An api for embedding Node in applications](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/23265)

> "[there is no ]`napi_env`[ just yet]."

[node-api: allow retrieval of add-on file name](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/37328) - [Missing module in Init](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/issues/449)

Andreas Rossberg - is AST parsing, or initialize [node.js abstraction for native c++](https://medium.com/@marcinbaraniecki/extending-node-js-with-native-c-modules-63294a91ce4), enough?

```
v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Index from C++!");
```

[Rising Stack](https://blog.risingstack.com/writing-native-node-js-modules/) - [Node Source](https://nodesource.com/blog/NAN-to-Node-API-migration-a-short-story)

```
"a macro implicit" parameter - bridge object between
C++ and JavaScript runtimes 
extract a function's parameters and set the return value.
#include <nan.h>

int build () {
  NAN_METHOD(Index) {
    info.GetReturnValue().Set(
      Nan::New("Index from C++!").ToLocalChecked()
    );
  }
}

  // Module initialization logic
NAN_MODULE_INIT(Initialize) {
  /*Export the `Index` function
    (equivalent to `export function Index (...)` in JS)*/
  NAN_EXPORT(target, Index);
}
```

New module "App" `Initialize` function from `NAN_MODULE_INIT` (an atomic?-macro)

"[__napi_something](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/blob/main/doc/node-gyp.md) doesn't [exist](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/issues/249#issuecomment-384830699)."

"[node-addon-API module](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples/blob/main/3_callbacks/node-addon-api/addon.cc) for C++ code ([N-API's C code's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59440434/11711280) headers)"

```
NODE_MODULE(App, Initialize);
```

> Sep 17, 2013, 4:42:17 AM to v8-u...@googlegroups.com "This comes up
> frequently, but the answer remains the same: scrap the idea. ;)
> Neither the V8 parser nor its AST are designed for external
> interfacing. In particular (1) V8's AST does not necessarily reflect
> JavaScript syntax 1-to-1, (2) we change it all the time, and (3) it
> depends on various V8 internals. And since all these points are
> important for V8, don't expect the situation to change.
>
> /Andreas"

[V8 c++: How to import module via code to script context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69808232/v8-c-how-to-import-module-via-code-to-script-context) (5/28/22, edit)

> "The export keyword may only be used in a [module interface unit](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/2019/03/31/modules-2.html).
> The keyword is attached to a declaration of an entity, and causes that
> declaration (and sometimes the definition) to become visible to module
> importers[ - except for] the export keyword in the module-declaration, which is just a re-use of the keyword (and does not actually “export” ...entities)."

[SyntheticModule::virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57681661/)

[ScriptCompiler::CompileModule()](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-11.14/da/da5/classv8_1_1_script_compiler.html#ab162cefa1c01678abfa4c1e9bfb8c53e) - "Corresponds to the [ParseModule](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-parsemodule) abstract operation in the ECMAScript [specification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57681661/11711280)."

```
Local<Function> foo_func = ...;//external
Local<Module> module = Module::CreateSyntheticModule(
    isolate, name,
    {String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "foo")},
    [](Local<Context> context, Local<Module> module) {
      module->SetSyntheticModuleExport(
        String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "foo"), foo_func
      );
    });
```

[Context-Aware addons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33561325/11711280) from `node.js`' commonjs modules

```
export module index;
export class Index {
  public:
    const char* app() {              
      return "done!";
    }
};
import index;
import <iostream>;

int main() {
    std::cout << Index().app() << '\n';
}
```

[node-addon-api](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api) (new)

[native abstractions](https://github.com/nodejs/nan) (old)

> "Thanks to the crazy changes in V8 (and some in Node core), keeping native addons compiling happily across versions, particularly 0.10 to 0.12 to 4.0, is a minor nightmare. The goal of this project is to store all logic necessary to develop native Node.js addons without having to inspect NODE_MODULE_VERSION and get yourself into a macro-tangle[ macro = extern atomics?]."

Scope Isolate (v8::Isolate), variable Local (v8::Local)

[typed_array_to_native.cc](https://github.com/vmoroz/node-addon-examples/blob/TypedArrayExample/typed_array_to_native/node-addon-api/typed_array_to_native.cc)

> "`require` is part of the Asynchronous Module Definition AMD API[, without "string-to-function" [`eval`/`new Function()`]](https://jameshfisher.com/2020/10/03/what-are-amd-modules/),"
> node.js makes objects, for it is written in `C++`.
>
> "[According to the algorithm](https://jameshfisher.com/2020/09/27/what-does-the-require-function-do-in-nodejs/), before finding
> `./node_modules/_/index.js`, it tried looking for express in the
> core Node.js modules. This didn’t exist, so it looked in `node_modules`,
> and found a directory called `_`. (If there was a
> `./node_modules/_.js`, it would load that directly.) It then
> loaded `./node_modules/_/package.json`, and looked for an `exports`
> field, but this didn’t exist. It also looked for a `main` field, but
> this didn’t exist either. It then fell back to `index.js`, which it
> found. ...`require()` looks for `node_modules` in all of the parent directories of the caller."

**But java?**

I won't accept this answer until it works, but this looks promising:

https://developer.oracle.com/databases/nashorn-javascript-part1.html

If not to run a jar file or something, in the Worker:

https://github.com/nodyn/jvm-npm

require and `build` equivalent in maven, first, use "dist/index.js".

Specifically: [`ScriptEngineManager`][21]

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15787930/11711280

Actually: `js.commonjs-require` [experimental](https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/js/Modules/)

https://docs.oracle.com/en/graalvm/enterprise/21/docs/reference-manual/js/Modules/

Alternatively/favorably: **commonjs builder in `C`** (v8 and node.js)

https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/u7elf4/what_are_your_thoughts_on_java_isolates_on_graalvm/

Here I will explore `v8`/[`node.js`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/src#environment) src `.h` and `.cc` for this purpose

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-darwin-8jcl2k?file=/src/c.cpp

I'm curious why there [is](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/learning/how-workers-works/) near machine-level `C` operability in Workers if not to use `std::ifstream`, **and**/or [build-locally](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/how-to-import-third-party-library-files-in-the-worker/16009), without node.js `require`.